# Permissions for ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES issue

Tags: windows-8, installshield, installshield-le

I have a config.txt file in my VS 2013 project. Here is its permissions for ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES : [image]

When I get a setup.exe by compiling an InstallShield LE project inside my solution, and when I run setup.exe, I get this config.txt under Program Files with these permissions :

[image]

I want all permissions to be allowed after extracting setup.exe. How can I do that? Thanks

Comment: One should avoid reducing the protections on files in shared locations like this. If possible, it's better to change the application to use a per-user location for the configuration file instead, perhaps copying a template from the program files location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the ProgramFiles folder and all subdirectories and files have only Read and Read&Execute permissions for security purposes. So, all files which copies to this folder inherite these permissions.
To change file or folder permissions with help of InstallShield, you could refer to the approtiate [documentation](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield16helplib/ConfiguringPrmssnsFile.htm). Also it could be achived by launching different tools for working with permissions, like subinacl.exe, icacls.exe, etc with help of custom actions.

But, as mentioned Michael Urman in comments, it's bad idea to place config files with write access under ProgramFiles (and other system folders), because of possible security issues.
So, I also reccomend to refrain from using this logic and store these files in User profile folders.

Comment: Pseudo +1 for the correct information (the first two sentences), as I cannot endorse a post that suggests changing permissions under ProgramFiles.

Comment: I understand yours concerns, but a lot of applications use ProgramFiles like folders, to store config\temp files. It's question to programmers - not to packagers. From another side, you could provide read&write access only to one config file to prevent possible security issues.

Comment: That limits the scope of the security issues, yes, but does not prevent them. We already know this aspect of the program is poorly written, so who's willing to assume that a corrupted or missing config file won't break the app?

Comment: Most likely, it will break it. And I agree with you - that is a bad practice for programmers to use ProgramFiles for storing files which should have write access. I should have added warning of doing this to answer.